# Key type from filtered objects

Tags: typescript, types

If I have the following value:

```js
const p1 = {
    mandatory: ["a", "b"],
    optional: ["c", "d"]
} as const;
```

then I can extract a type with keys from the `mandatory` field:

```js
type M1 = { [key in typeof p1["mandatory"][number]]: boolean };
```

In this case, `M1`'s type is:

```js
type M1 = {
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
};
```

---

But what if I have a value like this?

```js
const p2 = [
    { name: "a", isMandatory: true },
    { name: "b", isMandatory: true },
    { name: "c", isMandatory: false },
    { name: "d", isMandatory: false }
] as const;
```

I could extract a type that contains all of `p2`'s `name`s:

```js
type M2 = { [key in typeof p2[number]["name"]]: boolean };
```

which would result in:

```js
type M2 = {
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
    c: boolean;
    d: boolean;
};
```

How can I obtain a type in which only the fields with `isMandatory = true` are kept, such that `M2` ends up being the same as `M1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using one of TypeScript's [predefined conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#predefined-conditional-types), namely `Extract<U, X>`, which takes a union type `U` and keeps only those constituents which are assignable to `X`.  Like so:

```
type M2 = {
  [key in Extract<typeof p2[number], { isMandatory: true }>["name"]]: boolean
};
```

This should be equivalent to your `M1` type above.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJhgXhgbQFAxgbxmAQwFsBTALhgCIDKAaGASwgFkCwATAqEAJwE8KUHgFcSMAL60sufMXJUARnUYs2nbv0Eixk6XkKkKlYMqasOXXgJgAzAgBsIOqdn1yj7U6osbrdxzoYALowBBAwoJBQANwYGFB8cGLMSKg40mgA1iR8jGAwAKIAHkIEwFAAPAlJIDbwCGhgwkQKJDxB9HhmapaaMEKiEgB8aJQGJJRBQRQKICD2JGwY4rFAA)